# How to evaluate sensitivity and specifity of different tests

Tags: sensitivity-analysis, sensitivity-specificity

I am comparing two test using different cut-off values with  golden standart test . How is it to be reported. Is it sufficent to report sensitivity, specivity, PPV and NPV with 95  CI or should I evalute it with statistical test such as Mcnemar test or ROC. In some of papers, only the first one was reported whereas in some others, statistical tests were used. What is the correct method for this kind of situation?

Comment: ROC curve is common.

Comment: Is it possible to use ROC curve for binary classification. I have a contigency table and sencitivity specifity PPV NPV values.